# Connect and Bind Open LDAP using Novell.Directory.LDAP in C#

Tags: c#, ldap, openldap, aspnetcore-environment

I am trying to connect and bind using the Administrator user to LDAP and get the list of all users. Following is my code, which works for Microsoft Active Directory but not for **Open LDAP**. I am using `Novell.Directory.LDAP` in **C#**

```
var user = configuration.username + "@" + configuration.domainName;
LdapConnection connection = new() { SecureSocketLayer = false };
connection.Connect(configuration.Host, LdapConnection.DefaultPort);
connection.Bind(user, configuration.Password);
```

I researched and found that to bind Open LDAP, need an Admin account DN (Distinguished Name) only, and then it works.
But I am not provided with DN. Is it possible to bind the Open LDAP without Admin DN?

Comment: Were you the one who set up the server? Does it _require_ an account (sometimes OpenLDAP is set up to accept anonymous connections using a null bind)? If it does, then your question is pretty much "how do I access a server that requires accounts without having been given an account", which is something you discuss with the server's admins, not a programming issue.

Comment: I did the setup of the open LDAP server locally first, it requires an admin account. I do not want to do anonymous login. But still, I will see if I can.

Comment: Ok, so if you've set up the server, then just create a normal account and use its DN to bind?

Comment: so the DN is a must?

Comment: Yes. The "bind DN" is literally what LDAP uses as the username.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"Bind DN" is the LDAP equivalent of a username. If you do not want to allow anonymous access, then you will need to provide a username, and for LDAP simple bind that's always in the form of an entry DN.

Although Active Directory domain controllers accept plain usernames for simple-bind operations, that's generally an exception, not the rule. OpenLDAP does not support that; it requires a DN. (This is partly because Active Directory DCs have a "user name" attribute specifically defined in the AD schema; meanwhile OpenLDAP follows the X.500 schema, where the entire DN was *designed* to act as the username.)

If you want to create a username/password form, the usual approach used by services is to bind twice and perform a search:

1. User provides their username and password.
2. Program connects to LDAP and binds with its *own* (service account's) DN and password, then performs a search for an entry matching the provided username.
3. Program connects LDAP again and finally binds with the user's DN that was found (and with the provided password).

---

SASL PLAIN might *technically* be an alternative. Because SASL as a whole is protocol-independent, SASL binds do generally use a plain username, which OpenLDAP will *internally* translate to a bind DN. Unfortunately OpenLDAP cannot validate SASL PLAIN authentication all by itself; it would need an external account database (compatible with saslauthd), so in most cases that's just a headache.